# How to make the add New to insert row at the top of table instead at bottom while using angular-7 material table with save and edit buttons

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using the following angular7 material table with edit,save and delete buttons.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular7-material-table

I trying to addNew row but it is inserting at bottom of my table but I want it to insert at top/first position of my table.Someone please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function **unshift** in JavaScript which adds an element to the top of the array

Comment: Actually I guess the angular7 material table have some inbuilt methods which automatically generate the row at a particular index. and I am not sure how to ovverride those.Please provide me the complete solution.

Comment: First of all - there is an array you feed the table.
Secondly, you have source of the data you push to the array.
And finally, instead of array.push() use array.unshift() method to add the data to the beginning of the array you use to feed the table.

There can't be kinda "angular methods" to manipulate arrays. It's Javascript ;)

Answer (score 0):

`<MaterialTable option:{addRowPosition: 'first'}></MaterialTable>`

This will add new row on Top.

https://material-table.com/#/docs/all-props